# Having trouble using custom formula in conditional formatting on Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to get my list of names to conditional format based on which of another 2 columns a name appears.

This is my sheet, nothing complicated mostly a random generator for a game I am running.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xBv1QuMEohTGTZlFZ_FafB9QUA9z9pwk3oz0G3qEegk/edit?usp=sharing

Edit for more details:

Range of names to be formatted is found in range O2:O52 and is generated randomly from a range of names in A2:A1977 which is a mixture of male and female names.

The same names from A2:A1977 are separated into ranges Male (D2:D996) and Female (F2:F981).

Comment: what is the expected output? can you provide example?

Comment: if a name in the range O2:O52 matches a name in the range D2:D996 the colour the text Blue, if it matches a name in the range F2:F981 colour the text pink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

blue color:

```
=REGEXMATCH(O2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, D:D))
```

pink color:

```
=REGEXMATCH(O2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, F:F))
```

[image: 0]